# Maintain caret position in contenteditable div when html updates

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have an application that works like google docs where users can simultaneously work on a document. When one user's contenteditable div is changed, its html content is sent to the other users editing the document. Currently, using caret.js, I'm able to reset my cursor position to the offset it was at prior to the div update but the text I was currently writing is shifted over. How can I maintain my position relative to the character in the div my cursor was at?

Comment: Could you show us some code? or maybe a fiddle?